# Mysql opposite of join when element count is more than 1

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I need to do the opposite of inner join.

I have for example the table "TypeComponent". I've added the column MaxAllowed

```
IDTypeElement    Type           MaxAllowed
   Type1         battery            1
   Type2         temperature        1
   Type3         pressure           3
```

I have the table Transmitter in which I can have only 1 battery, 1 temperature and 3 pressures elements

```
ID    IDTransmitter   IDTypeElement   
1         A              Type1
2         A              Type2
3         A              Type3
4         A              Type3
5         A              Type3

6         B              Type1
7         B              Type3
```

When we add a component to the transmitter, I need to be able to remove the TypeElement that we already have. For example, the transmitter "B", I want to be able to get, in my listbox, only the component allowed. Here, I mean, the listbox must contain only "Type2"(temperature) and "Type3"(pressure) because, we are allowed to have only one "Type1"(battery) et we already got one. In another hand, we can have 3 "Type3"(pressure) and we only have one.

So, I try to work with that query

```
SELECT IDTypeElement from typeelement
WHERE IDTypeElement not in (SELECT IDTypeElement FROM transmitter WHERE IDTransmitter="B")
```

My problem is, I want to be able to grab "Type3" because we allow to have 3 times "Type3", but with that query, I only get "Type2"... Is there a way to tell a limit of an element? Could someone help me please?

Hope you understand my question (and my english).

**If I take the example with IDTranmistter:  B, using the query similar to the one above, I would like to have, in my listbox : "Type2" and "Type3"**

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add your expected (or desired) output?

Comment: You need to have that business rule stored in one of the table i.e. how much quantity of each part is needed in a battery. Without which it will be very hard to write such query

Comment: Ok, I've added the desired results. @Harsh, I've added a "Max Allowed" column in the TypeElement table... but what should I do with that column?

Comment: Please check my answer and sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8743/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```
Select e.IDTypeElement
from TypeComponent e LEFT JOIN
(
select IDTransmitter, IDTypeElement, count(*) as used
from Transmitter 
group by IDTransmitter,IDTypeElement
) t
on e.IDTypeElement = t.IDTypeElement
and t.IDTransmitter = 'B'
where (e.MaxAllowed-ifnull(t.used,0))>0
```

Please check sqlfiddle @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8743/5

Answer (score 0):

you can do a left join

**Tables:**

```
mysql> select * from typecomponent
    -> ;
+---------------+-------------+------------+
| idtypeelement | type        | maxallowed |
+---------------+-------------+------------+
| Type1         | battery     |          1 |
| Type2         | temperature |          1 |
| Type3         | pressure    |          3 |
+---------------+-------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from transmitter;
+----+---------------+---------------+
| id | idtransmitter | idtypeelement |
+----+---------------+---------------+
|  1 | A             | Type1         |
|  2 | A             | Type2         |
|  3 | A             | Type3         |
|  4 | A             | Type3         |
|  5 | A             | Type3         |
|  6 | B             | Type1         |
|  7 | B             | Type3         |
+----+---------------+---------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Query:**

```
select idtypeelement from (select tc.idtypeelement, tc.maxallowed, count(t.idtypeelement) as usedComponents from typecomponent tc left join transmitter t on t.idtypeelement = tc.idtypeelement and t.idtransmitter='B' group by 1,2 having usedComponents < tc.maxallowed) t;
+---------------+
| idtypeelement |
+---------------+
| Type2         |
| Type3         |
+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: oh.. well, looks like Harsh beat me to it.